# Break line while seeing a date format

Tags: java, regex

My pgrm returns news from a webpage in string format. I want to split the string each time when it sees a date format as dd-mm-yyyy. Is it possible to split each time it sees a date???

```
Pattern patern=Pattern.compile("-");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

My data format is like this

`String s="Meow looks like cocaine, is 20 times cheaper, more dangerous, and not illegal; with children as young as 14 addicted to it, CM Devendra Fadnavis has asked the Centre to ban it under the Narcotics Act 18-Dec-2014l The girl was allegedly raped by a school supervisor last week; an activist wrote to the DCP following which the police approached and convinced the survivor’s family to register the offence 18-Dec-2014 Former principal of a Mumbai school has written to education minister against reinstatement of a teacher, accused of sexually harassing nearly 40 Std X students, who is now out on bail 19-Dec-2014"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that pattern, it will split on every "-", but group 1 does not even exist because you use no groups in your regex.

What you want is easier done with `String.split`, that is

```
String[] split = s.split("\\d{2}-\\w{3}-\\d{4}");
for (String x :split)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

The regex explained: 2 digits followed by a dash, then 3 word characters (afaik the short names for months are all 3 letters followed by another dash and the year in 4 digits.

Comment: Or, to keep the date in the string, `s.split("(?<=\\d{2}-\\w{3}-\\d{4})")`.

Comment: Right. When OP said split, I automatically assumed the behavior of the split method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code block. This will add line-break.

```
String s="Meow looks like cocaine, is 20 times cheaper, more dangerous, and not illegal; with children as young as 14 addicted to it, CM Devendra Fadnavis has asked the Centre to ban it under the Narcotics Act 18-Dec-2014l The girl was allegedly raped by a school supervisor last week; an activist wrote to the DCP following which the police approached and convinced the survivor’s family to register the offence 18-Dec-2014 Former principal of a Mumbai school has written to education minister against reinstatement of a teacher, accused of sexually harassing nearly 40 Std X students, who is now out on bail 19-Dec-2014 ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(([0-9]{2})-([a-zA-Z]{3})-([0-9]{4}))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        s = s.replaceAll(matcher.group(1),matcher.group(1)+"\n");
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: @liker Korkut...but one problem still occurs...when I return this data into jsp page using model attribute it prints as entire string without line breaks...how can I resolve this????..model.addAttribute("news",news+"\n");

Comment: You can change with "<br/>" instead of "\n" for html tag.

Answer (score 1):

seeing that your format of date is dd-Mon-yyyy, this is the regex i came up with:
'[0123][\d]-[JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptvc]-\d\d\d\d'

[0123][\d] matches the date, which can have either 0,1,2 or 3 in the tens digit and in the ones place it can have any decimal

[JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptvc] matches the month, i have taken the alphabets from different month, first alphabet in caps rest two in small.

\d\d\d\d matches the years(0000-9999)
Hope this is clear. This regex works in python, have not tested in java but it should work fine.

```
String exp='[0123][\d]-[JFMASOND][aepuco][nbrylgptvc]-\d\d\d\d';
String[] split = s.split(exp)
for (String x :split)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```